# PHPMailer weird header information in inbox

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

If I want to send a mail with PHPMailer it works but not as great as I expected and hoped somebody has a solution.

From Name & Email are filled in but yet it appears like this in my mailbox:
[image]

Now I used this script to send my mail but I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I would suggest you to enclose variables with double quotes, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong syntax here. Try this:

```
$email->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
```

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/sendmail.phps